# Heißt es Bayrisch oder Bairisch?

Tags: bavarian

Heißt es Bayrisch oder Bairisch? Ich habe hier beide Schreibweisen gesehen, kannte vorher aber nur erstere.

Comment: Bayrisch heißt das.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Laut Wikipedia ist ["bairisch"](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bairisch) die heutzutage übliche Schreibweise für den "Dialektverbund" der bairischen Sprachen, der aber nicht auf den Freistaat Bayern begrenzt ist ([Karte](http://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Datei:Bairisches_Mundartgebiet.PNG&filetimestamp=20090412175639))

Der Begriff "bayerisch" ist [begrenzt auf den Freistaat Bayern:](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bairische_Dialekte#Etymologie)

> Das Wort „Bairisch“ ist ein dialektologischer Begriff, der sich aus der Bezeichnung der ersten „deutschsprachigen“ Besiedler und ihrer Stammesdialekte in althochdeutscher Zeit ableitet. **Es ist zu trennen von dem Wort „bayerisch“, einem geographisch-politischen Begriff, der sich auf den Freistaat Bayern bezieht, wo auch nichtbairische Dialekte verbreitet sind.**
>
> ...
>
> **Bairisch und Bayern**
>
> In der Sprachwissenschaft wird die Schreibweise Bairisch verwendet und bairisches Sprachgebiet. Im Unterschied dazu bezeichnet das Wort Bayerisch keine Sprachdialekte, sondern bezieht sich ausschließlich auf ein politisches Territorium, den Freistaat Bayern. Die unterschiedlichen Schreibweisen wurden eingeführt, weil einerseits in Bayern außer den bairischen (in Altbayern) auch fränkische und schwäbisch-alemannische (in Franken und Bayerisch-Schwaben) Mundarten gesprochen werden, andererseits die bairischen Dialekte sich nicht auf Bayern beschränken, sondern auch in Österreich, Südtirol und in einigen isolierten Sprachinseln der Schweiz gesprochen werden. Die historische Schreibweise Baiern für das gewachsene bayerische Staatsgebilde wurde mit Anordnung vom 20. Oktober 1825 durch den philhellenischen König Ludwig I. durch die Schreibweise Bayern, also mit dem Buchstaben y, ersetzt.